# React JS - Undefined variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to modify a simple react app, but I don't know a lot about react.

I'm trying to set a data-attribute to my iframe. This value should be taken from localStorage.getItem().

here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import createReactClass from 'create-react-class';
import {Col, Row} from "react-bootstrap";




const SamplePage = createReactClass({
  displayName: 'Plugin',
  render() {
  
    if (localStorage.getItem('sessionId')){
        let sessionId = localStorage.getItem('sessionId');
    }
    else{
        let sessionId = "";
    }
    
    return (
        
          <iframe src="http://myurl.x/" frameborder="0" style={{height:"85vh",position:"relative"}} id={sessionId} width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        
    );
  }
});

export default SamplePage;
```

Unfortunately I get a `"sessionId is not defined"` error.

Again, I don't know react and it seems really different to classic js for me.

Does anyone knows whats I misunderstood ?

Comment: I would not expect that error from the code you've provided. Did you leave anything else out when asking your question? Ps, `create-react-class` is based on a really old way of making react components. If you have the option to use more recent react code you may want to do so.

Comment: Hi, in fact I can't use a more recent react version. It's mandatory for me to use this version because it is the version used by the software running the web plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (localStorage.getItem("sessionId")) {
  let sessionId = localStorage.getItem("sessionId");
} else {
  let sessionId = "";
}
```

`let` variables are scoped to the block that they're contained in. So the first variable is only usable inside the `if`, and the second only inside the `else`. Once you get past the else, there is no `sessionId` variable, and thus `id={sessionId}` throws an error.

To fix this, change the code to what you originally showed:

```
let sessionId;
if (localStorage.getItem("sessionId")) {
  sessionId = localStorage.getItem("sessionId");
} else {
  sessionId = "";
}
```

That way, there's a single sessionId variable, who's scope is the entire render function.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared variable `sessionId` inside the `if` and `else` blocks, hence its scope is limited to the corresponding blocks, whether it is `if` block or `else` block. Your error is due to this code here:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('sessionId')){
    let sessionId = localStorage.getItem('sessionId');
}
else {
    let sessionId = "";
}
```

Instead, you should delcare `sessionId` variable outside `if` and `else` scopes to use it outside them.

```
let sessionId="";
if (localStorage.getItem('sessionId')){
    sessionId = localStorage.getItem('sessionId');
}
```

This will resolve your **error**!!!

**Advice**: Please do clear your JS basics before starting ReactJS

Answer (score 0):

You define `sessionId` in a local scope and access it outside of the scope that is why the error says `sessionId is not defined`. You need to create a state that hold `sessionId`, and update the `sessionId` by `this.setState`

```
const SamplePage = createReactClass({
  displayName: 'Plugin',
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {sessionId: ""};
  },
  setSessionId: function(sessionId) {
    this.setState({sessionId});
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){

    if (localStorage.getItem('sessionId')){
        const sessionId = localStorage.getItem('sessionId');
        this.setSessionId(sessionId)
    }
    else{
        this.setSessionId("")
    }
  },
  render() {
  
    
    return (
        
          <iframe src="http://myurl.x/" frameborder="0" style={{height:"85vh",position:"relative"}} id={this.state.sessionId} width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! Unfortunately, it's causing this error https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=185. I'll look for a solution for this

Comment: I forgot to move the code that handles sessionId to componentDidMount. That is why it triggers infinite rerendering. Updated my answer. My approach makes sure that when sessionId changes, the component will be updated. In the other hand, the accepted answer does not handle that.